# Why is AdMob paying less for Interstitial Ad clicks?

Tags: advertising, android, revenue

So, last month my app got from AdMob about $3 for all the ads displayed, and for a click on an Interstitial Ad I was getting paid about **$0.40**.

From the start of January 2020 I noticed that the users clicked from time to time the ads but as payment for each click I was getting paid between **$0.03 - 0.06**, which is really low considering the fact that the impressions from each month are almost equal (**1540 impressions for December 2019, 1450 impressions for January 2020**).

I mention that my app has 5 activities, and in AdMob I created 5 Interstitial Ads(**two of them I added this month**) for each of the activities, is this thing wrong?

Is it a problem that I **reload** the Interstitial Ads immediately after user closes the Ad?

So am I doing something wrong here ?